# Is there any 3rd party software to modify SSIS packages?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I've been working on some data transformation tasks in SSIS. Visual Studio has gotten better in 2008 in it's usability, but I find there are some things that annoy me (i.e. When I delete something in the Package Explorer it refreshs the whole screen bringing me back to the top of the tree. Also, lack of some keyboard shortcuts.) Is there any other DTSx package editors out there or plug-ins for VS, and are they worth the trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For things like this, believe it or not, the XML is pretty readable if you open the file as XML in visual studio and do a Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D to reformat the XML document.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at [Rhino.ETL](https://rhino-tools.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/rhino-tools/trunk/rhino-etl/)? It's a in-code replacement for SSIS, although I haven't used it personally.

[Object Oriented ETL using RhinoETL](http://www.codinginstinct.com/2008/12/object-oriented-etl-using-rhinoetl.html)

[Rhino ETL 2.0](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/01/16/Rhino-ETL-2.0.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

CodePlex project [BIDS Helper](http://www.codeplex.com/bidshelper) helps a lot when editing SSIS package. It is plug-in for BIDS. I use it in my work and find it quite useful.